# Symfony PunkAveFileUploaderBundle > imagename before handleFileUpload

Tags: symfony

The [Symfony2 PunkAve FileUpload Bundle](https://github.com/punkave/symfony2-file-uploader-bundle) works, but because of the returns inside the UploadHandler of BlueImp, it is not possible to get the filename.

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * @Route("/upload")
 * @Template()
 */
public function uploadAction(Request $request)
{
    $editId = $this->getRequest()->get('editId');
    if (!preg_match('/^\d+$/', $editId))
    {
        throw new Exception("Bad edit id");
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('Foobar:Foobar')->find($editId);

    $destinationFolder = 'test';

    $fileUploader = $this->get('punk_ave.file_uploader');

    $imageName = $fileUploader->handleFileUpload(array('folder' => $destinationFolder ));

    $imageEntity = new \Foobar\Entity\Image();
    $imageEntity->setImage($imageName);
    $imageEntity->setFolder($destinationFolder);
    $em->persist($media);
    $em->flush();

    return true;
}
```

The example above uploads the image.

The variable $imageName triggers the fileUploadHandler. There is somewhere a return, why it doesn't go the the next lines where it should save the imagename.

How can I still get it working in Symfony? To save the filename in the Entity after he handled the upload?

Answer (score 1):

As they said in documentation: *handleFileUpload DOES NOT RETURN as the response is generated in native PHP by BlueImp's UploadHandler class*. `handleFileUpload` has `exit(0);` at the end so when you call it then entire process stops there. If you want to save files to database you should do it in action which handles request (from documentation's example it will be `editAction`) and there, again as documentation said, *use getFiles to get the list of filenames and mirror that in your database as you see fit*.